# Is it safe to modify underlying file if it's mounted by losetup?

Tags: linux, loop-device

I've got a raw binary file and I need to access it (read-only) as a block device, for compatibility reasons. I mount this file through losetup eg. losetup /dev/loop0 file.bin. The block device is only used for reading. What happens if I modify the underlying file directly (not through block device) while it's still mounted? Is it a safe thing to do?